# Is it possible to create tiles with transparent background using Qtiles?

Tags: qgis, tiles

I had created the tiles from shapefile using qtiles plugin in QGIS and that shapefile layer is a label layer created using MMQGIS plugin. But the thing is I want that tiles with transparent background. Can anyone shed some light on this?

**Update**: I already tried with layer properties 'transparency' along with qtiles 'transparency' it didn't worked well. The generated tiles were not clear.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can set the "background transparency" to 0 which will make QTiles render PNG tiles with transparent background if applicable by your styles.

Comment: where is the "background transparency" property located? I have found the "layer transparency" but this will set the entire layer transparent, and not only the background.

Comment: In the QTiles dialog.

Answer (score -1):

I had completed this activity using TileMill to generate background transparent tiles with the help of CartoCSS.